# How do I scrape ONLY <div class ='quotetext'> from a website using python?

Tags: python, web-scraping, quotes, chatbot

I am trying to import the Einstein quotes from this website:

https://www.goodreads.com/author/quotes/9810.Albert_Einstein

I want only the quote text. Not even his name, or anything else. Just the text, to help build a markhov chain chat bot.

This is the code I have:

```
from lxml import html
import requests

page = requests.get('https://www.goodreads.com/author/quotes/9810.Albert_Einstein')
tree = html.fromstring(page.content)

quotes = tree.xpath('//div[@class="quoteText"]/text()')


print quotes
```

And this is the output:

> [u"\n      \u201cTwo things are infinite: the universe and human
>   stupidity; and I'm not sure about the universe.\u201d\n  ", u' 
>   \u2015\n    ', '\n', u'\n      \u201cThere are only two ways to live
>   your life. One is as though nothing is a miracle. The other is as
>   though everything is a miracle.\u201d\n  ', u'  \u2015\n    ', '\n',
>   u'\n      \u201cI am enough of an artist to draw freely upon my
>   imagination. Imagination is more important than knowledge. Knowledge
>   is limited. Imagination encircles the world.\u201d\n  ', u'  \u2015\n 
>   ', '\n', u"\n      \u201cIf you can't explain it to a six year old,
>   you don't understand it yourself.\u201d\n  ", u'  \u2015\n    ', '\n',
>   u'\n      \u201cIf you want your children to be intelligent, read them
>   fairy tales. If you want them to be more intelligent, read them more
>   fairy tales.\u201d\n  ', u'  \u2015\n    ', '\n', u'\n
>   \u201cLogic will get you from A to Z; imagination will get you
>   everywhere.\u201d\n  ', u'  \u2015\n    ', '\n', u'\n      \u201cLife
>   is like riding a bicycle. To keep your balance, you must keep
>   moving.\u201d\n  ', u'  \u2015\n    ', '\n', u'\n      \u201cAnyone
>   who has never made a mistake has never tried anything new.\u201d\n  ',
>   u'  \u2015\n    ', '\n', u'\n      \u201cI speak to everyone in the
>   same way, whether he is the garbage man or the president of the
>   university.\u201d\n  ', u'  \u2015\n    ', '\n', u"\n      \u201cWhen
>   you are courting a nice girl an hour seems like a second. When you sit
>   on a red-hot cinder a second seems like an hour. That's
>   relativity.\u201d\n  ", u'  \u2015\n    ', '\n', u'\n      \u201cNever
>   memorize something that you can look up.\u201d\n  ', u'  \u2015\n
>   ', '\n', u'\n      \u201cA clever person solves a problem. A wise
>   person avoids it.\u201d\n  ', u'  \u2015\n    ', '\n', u'\n
>   \u201cScience without religion is lame, religion without science is
>   blind.\u201d\n  ', u'  \u2015\n    ', '\n', u'\n      \u201cReality is
>   merely an illusion, albeit a very persistent one.\u201d\n  ', u' 
>   \u2015\n    ', '\n', u'\n      \u201cIf we knew what it was we were
>   doing, it would not be called research, would it?\u201d\n  ', u' 
>   \u2015\n    ', '\n', u'\n      \u201cI have no special talents. I am
>   only passionately curious.\u201d\n  ', u'  \u2015\n    ', '\n', u'\n
>   \u201cIf a cluttered desk is a sign of a cluttered mind, of what,
>   then, is an empty desk a sign?\u201d\n  ', u'  \u2015\n    ', '\n',
>   u'\n      \u201cThe important thing is to not stop questioning.
>   Curiosity has its own reason for existence. One cannot help but be in
>   awe when he contemplates the mysteries of eternity, of life, of the
>   marvelous structure of reality. It is enough if one tries merely to
>   comprehend a little of this mystery each day.', u'\xe2\x80\x94"Old
>   Man\'s Advice to Youth: \'Never Lose a Holy Curiosity.\'" ', u' (2 May
>   1955) p. 64\u201d\n  ', u'  \u2015\n    ', '\n', u'\n      \u201cTry
>   not to become a man of success. Rather become a man of value.\u201d\n 
>   ', u'  \u2015\n    ', '\n', u'\n      \u201cAny fool can know. The
>   point is to understand.\u201d\n  ', u'  \u2015\n    ', '\n', u'\n
>   \u201cA human being is a part of the whole called by us universe, a
>   part limited in time and space. He experiences himself, his thoughts
>   and feeling as something separated from the rest, a kind of optical
>   delusion of his consciousness. This delusion is a kind of prison for
>   us, restricting us to our personal desires and to affection for a few
>   persons nearest to us. Our task must be to free ourselves from this
>   prison by widening our circle of compassion to embrace all living
>   creatures and the whole of nature in its beauty.\u201d\n  ', u' 
>   \u2015\n    ', '\n', u'\n      \u201cOnce you can accept the universe
>   as matter expanding into nothing that is something, wearing stripes
>   with plaid comes easy.\u201d\n  ', u'  \u2015\n    ', '\n', u'\n
>   \u201cIf I were not a physicist, I would probably be a musician. I
>   often think in music. I live my daydreams in music. I see my life in
>   terms of music.\u201d\n  ', u'  \u2015\n    ', '\n', u'\n
>   \u201cThe world as we have created it is a process of our thinking. It
>   cannot be changed without changing our thinking.\u201d\n  ', u' 
>   \u2015\n    ', '\n', u'\n      \u201cI know not with what weapons
>   World War III will be fought, but World War IV will be fought with
>   sticks and stones.\u201d\n  ', u'  \u2015\n    ', '\n', u'\n
>   \u201cYou never fail until you stop trying.\u201d\n  ', u'  \u2015\n
>   ', '\n', u'\n      \u201cGreat spirits have always encountered violent
>   opposition from mediocre minds.\u201d\n  ', u'  \u2015\n    ', '\n',
>   u'\n      \u201cThe most beautiful experience we can have is the
>   mysterious. It is the fundamental emotion that stands at the cradle of
>   true art and true science.\u201d\n  ', u'  \u2015\n    ', ',\n    ',
>   '\n    \n\n  \n', '\n\n\n', '\n\n', u'\n      \u201cGravitation is not
>   responsible for people falling in love.\u201d\n  ', u'  \u2015\n    ',
>   '\n', u"\n      \u201cIt is not that I'm so smart. But I stay with the
>   questions much longer.\u201d\n  ", u'  \u2015\n    ', '\n']

I feel like there must be a better way to do this altogether, since this is printing in list form and has all this extra text, but I am hitting walls everywhere. Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A python 2x script using module beautifulsoup

```
from __future__ import print_function
from re import sub
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
from urllib2 import urlopen
urlpage=urlopen("https://www.goodreads.com/author/quotes/9810.Albert_Einstein").read()
bswebpage=BeautifulSoup(urlpage)
results=bswebpage.findAll("div",{'class':"quoteText"})
for result in results:
    print("\nQuotes\n")
    print(sub("&ldquo;|.&rdquo;","","".join(result.contents[0:1]).strip()))
```

results on my side

```
Quotes

Two things are infinite: the universe and human stupidity; and I'm not sure about the universe

Quotes

There are only two ways to live your life. One is as though nothing is a miracle. The other is as though everything is a miracle

Quotes

I am enough of an artist to draw freely upon my imagination. Imagination is more important than knowledge. Knowledge is limited. Imagination encircles the world
..............................................
..............................................
```

Comment: Thanks so much dude! Works perfectly.